# captcha doen't validate in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, captcha, yii2-advanced-app

tips : username and email is check by ajaxValidation with validate method.

all is correct but i guess captcha is changed in server but the old picture is in client.

i googling alot no result found.

this is view:

```
<?php
    $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin([
                'id' => 'form-signup',
                'action' => 'signup',
                'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
                'enableClientValidation' => true,
                'validationUrl' => 'validation',
                'validateOnBlur' => true,
                'fieldConfig' => [
                    'template' => '<div class="col-md-4" >{label}{input}{error}</div>'
                ]
    ]);
    ?>

    <?= $form->field($signup, 'username', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'name') ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'family') ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'mobile') ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'password_repeat')->passwordInput() ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'email', ['enableAjaxValidation' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($signup, 'verifyCode', ['enableAjaxValidation' => false])->widget(yii\captcha\Captcha::className()) ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= yii\helpers\Html::submitButton('signup', ['class' => 'btn btn-green margin-right', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>

    </div>
```

controller:

```
        $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($model->validate()) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                    return $this->goHome();
                }
            }
        } else {
    ;
            \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('/partials/_signup', ['signup' => $model]);
    }
```

ajax validation controller method:

```
  public function actionValidation() {
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
        return \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
}
```

model:

```
 public $name;
public $family;
public $mobile;
public $username;
public $email;
public $password;
public $password_repeat;
public $verifyCode;

   public function rules() {
    return [
        [['name', 'family', 'mobile'], 'default'],
        ['name', 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ['family', 'string', 'max' => 50],
        ['mobile', 'string', 'max' => 11],
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
        [['username'], 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\frontend\models\User', 'message' => 'username already taken.'],
        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'string', 'max' => 255],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\frontend\models\User', 'message' => 'email name already taken.'],
        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'max' => 255],
        ['password_repeat', 'string', 'min' => 6, 'max' => 255],
        ['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
        ['verifyCode', 'captcha'],
    ];
}
```

**there is no behaviour in controller**

Answer (score -1):

1. enableAjaxValidation of a form takes precedence over that of a field, so it's hard to tell what exactly you are trying to do with your current settings
2. Make sure you have verifyCode declared as an attribute on your model
3. Captcha verification code is saved in the session. The session key is a combination of controller's and action's ids. So you might have a misconfigured session. Or your captcha's action name is not 'captcha', - you are missing that part of your source code in the question.